# Accessing global function variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, namespaces

Somehow I thought you could define a function as a global variable and access its internal variables.
Example:

```
var func = function(){
    var connected = true;
}

console.log(func.connected);
```

However, this still comes up as "undefined".
I thought it would be interesting to "namespace" certain variables like this.

I don't want to use objects/lists/dictionaries (how you prefer to call them) because you can `delete` those elements.

Comment: So what if you can `delete` them?  You can delete anything else, too.

Comment: `I don't want to use objects because you can delete those elements` Sorry to disappoint you but functions are objects too: `delete func`. Indeed everything in javascript are objects.

Comment: Yes, but you can't delete a variable that has been declared using `var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.
In fact, it doesn't even make sense.
Each call to a function produces a separate set of local variables.

You should use objects to create namespaces, even though you can `delete` them.

If you want to, you can also make a class:
Note that you need to make an *instance* of the class:

```
function MyClass() { 
    this.connected = true;
}

var myInstance = new MyClass();
console.log(myInstance.connected);
```

However, you should not use classes to create singleton namespaces; there is no point.

Instead, you should write

```
var myNamespace = { connected: true };

console.log(myNamespace.connected);
```

Answer (score 2):

`var` inside a function makes it private. use `this.connected = true` to make it public.

```
var func = function(){
    this.connected = true;
}
```

PS - As far as I know, all properties of an object **are** deletable unless they're non-enumerable, which I don't think you can easily specify. You should use `this.connected` even though it is deletable.

There is a good readup [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) on public/private methods and "privileged" methods.

EDIT: I assumed you knew about instantiating.. anyway just do `x = new func` to create an instance, then `x.connected`.

Comment: @SLaks - what won't work? I already specified about the `delete` operator. And him using `new` is implied.

Comment: Why do you think `new` is implied?

Answer (score 1):

by using `var` it is private.

use it like this:

```
var func = function(){
    this.connected = true;
}
var namespace = new func();

console.log(namespace.connected);
```

remember that it needs to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON notation like this:

```
var func = {
   connected:true,
   func:function(){
     func.connected = true;
   }
}
console.log(func.connected);
```

Comment: Your second version will work, but has too many `func` s.  You need different names.

Comment: What do you mean too many func s? And why do you need different names? for what? JSON is the perfect why to create singletons and namespaces your variables and functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyClass = function() {
    function clazz() {
        this.message = "Hello"; //instance variable
    }

    clazz.connected = true; //static variable

    return clazz;
}();


alert(MyClass.connected)
alert(new MyClass().message)
```